# How To Think Like A Computer Scientist (Chapter 9): I don't understand the following

Tags: python

I'm finding difficulting what exactly the doctest in the following code is looking for in the function.

Can someone make it more clear for me, please?

[Question 14](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html):

> 1. Write functions row_times_column and matrix_mult:

```
def row_times_column(m1, row, m2, column):
    """
      >>> row_times_column([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 0, [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 0)
      19
      >>> row_times_column([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 0, [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 1)
      22
      >>> row_times_column([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 1, [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 0)
      43
      >>> row_times_column([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 1, [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 1)
      50
    """
def matrix_mult(m1, m2):
   """
      >>> matrix_mult([[1, 2], [3,  4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]])
      [[19, 22], [43, 50]]
      >>> matrix_mult([[1, 2, 3], [4,  5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 1], [2, 3]])
      [[31, 19], [85, 55]]
      >>> matrix_mult([[7, 8], [9, 1], [2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
      [[39, 54, 69], [13, 23, 33], [14, 19, 24]]
    """
```

> Add your new functions to matrices.py and be sure it passes the
>   doctests above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its asking you to implement some matrix multiplication methods.

In the first one, given a matrix, multiply the row of m1 x the column of m2. The first one given is:

```
1 2   times   5 6
3 4           7 8
```

but we only want row 0 times col 0, so it would be

```
[1 2] x 5 
        7
```

= 5+14 = 19. And so on for the others...

The second function wants a full matrix multiplication. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 3):

The first function, first example in docstring: take the zeroth row from the first matrix (`[1, 2]`) and multiply it by the zeroth column of the second matrix (`[5, 7]`)

```
1 x 5 + 2 x 7 = 19
```

The second function is just standard [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). You can use the first function to answer this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first function, `row_times_column` multiplies the nth row of the first matrix by the mth column of the second matrix. In the first doctest, for example, `n = 0` and `m = 0`, so we multiply the row matrix `[1, 2]` by the column matrix `[5, 7]` to get `1 * 5 + 2 * 7` which is equal to `19` as specified.

The second function is the generalization, and you have to [multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) the first matrix by the second. You are probably supposed to use the first function. The linked article shows how to get matrix multiplication from a combination of row by column multiplications.